# Google Apps Script: how to make this autocomplete library work in UI?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add an autocomplete feature (a Ui in a popup window in a spreadsheet) in my Google Spreadsheet using this Google Apps Script suggest box library from Romain Vialard and James Ferreira's book:

```
function doGet() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var list = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    var emails = contacts[i].getEmails();
    if(emails[0] != undefined){
      list.push(emails[0].getAddress());
    }
  }
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var suggestBox = SuggestBoxCreator.createSuggestBox(app, 'contactPicker', 200, list);
  app.add(suggestBox);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);
}


function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "my_sheet_name" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1) {
      doGet();
   // testFunction();
    }
  }
}
```

But when I start editing column 1 of "my_sheet_name" nothing hapens (The `testFunction()` works as expected). I've already installed the Suggest Box library. So, why the doGet() function doesn't work?

Here is my test spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtHEC6UUJ_rsdFBWMkhfWUQ0MEs2ck5OY1BsYjRSLXc&usp=drive_web#gid=0

Comment: please re-read your question and edit function name ;-)

Comment: I edit it =) And put my test spreadsheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script: how to make suggest box library to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872157/google-apps-script-how-to-make-suggest-box-library-to-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onEdit is a simple trigger , if you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR) you'll learn that "They cannot access any services that require authentication as that user."

And your `doGet` function uses `ContactsApp`, that's why it fails silently.

Use another name and set up an `installable on Edit trigger` that will ask for authorization. That said, it won't return any data to your spreadsheet (as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872157/google-apps-script-how-to-make-suggest-box-library-to-work) in your other post and read carefully the chapter about installable triggers).

See also [this doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service?hl=fr-FR) about serverHandlers and how to implement it in UiApp.

Comment: Hi, @Serge, I ask other suggest box autocomplete question (without authorization need and I'm still with problems -- but I won't give up! =)

Comment: Try to get it first to work from a menu item. Within onEdit/installed trigger its more restrictive.